# How to know if a list has an even or odd number of elements

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How can I find out if there is even, or odd, number of elements in an arbitrary list.

I tried `list.index()` to get all of the indices... but I still don't know how I can tell the program what is an even and what is an odd number.

Comment: you can get the number of elements of a list using the `len()` builtin function

Comment: @goncalopp... but how would I tell it is odd number of even

Comment: `len(your_list) % 2 == 0`

Comment: @dm03514 ... what does your code mean

Comment: @user3029969: It does what you asked for.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the built in function `len()` for this.

**[Python Doc -- len()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)**

Gets the length (# of elements) of any arbitrary list.

```
myList = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

if len(myList) % 2 == 0:
    print ("even")
else
    print ("odd")
```

**Define function that returns a bool (true or false).**

```
def is_even(myList):

    if len(myList) % 2 == 0:
        return true
    else:
        return false

main():

    myList = [0,1,2,3]
    theListIsEven = is_even(myList)  # will be true in this example
                                     # because 4 items in myList

    if theListIsEven(myList) == True:
        # do something
    else:
        # do something else

    return 0
```

**The modulus operator** `%` **gives the remainder.**

EX:    7 % 2 = 1

- Closest number to 7 that 2 will divide evenly is 6
- Which is 1 away from 7.
- Thus, remainder of 1 for 7 % 2.

EX:   4 % 2 = 0

- Any even number n will give 0 as the remainder when n % 2
- Because n has divided evenly by 2

Answer (score 4):

All you need is

```
len(listName)
```

Which will give you the length.

I guess you could also do this then

```
if len(listName) % 2 == 0:
    return True  # the number is even!
else:
    return False # the number is odd!
```

Comment: but how would I tell it is odd number of even for any arbitrary list

Comment: By applying modulus 2 on the returned length of the list. Which is exactly what codehorse did in his answer.

Comment: @user3029969, the code `len(listName) % 2` is dividing the number of elements in the array by 2 and returning the remainder. If the remainder is 0, then the number of elements is divisible by 2, which means it is even. If it returns 1, then it is odd.

Comment: `return len(listName) % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 4):

```
your_list = [1,2,3,(4,5)]

# modulo operation finds the remainder of division of one number by another.
if len(your_list) % 2 == 0:
    print "Even Number"
else:
    print"number is odd"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if len(mylist)%2==0:
     #even
else:
     #odd
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def has_even_length(some_sequence):
    return not len(some_sequence)%2

def has_odd_length(some_sequence):
    return bool(len(some_sequence)%2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even numbers are divisible by 2. Odd numbers are not.

`len(X)` will get the length of `X`

If the length of `X` is divisible by 2, then it is an Even number
If the length of `X` is not divisible by 2 then it is an Odd Number

`len(X)%2` returns the "remainder" of a division problem

for example `5%2` will return `1` which is NOT zero, (because 5 divided by 2 is 2 with a remainder of 1), therefore it is not even.
Same thing as `6%4` which would return a `2`, because 6 divided by 4 is 1 with a remainder of 2.

so `len(X)%2` where `X` is your list, will return either a 1, indicating it is Odd, or a 0 indicating it is Even.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to be bitwise about it you could also use.

```
if len(mylist)&1:
    print("odd")
else:
    print("even")
```

this is really Nice looking if you know your list is more likely to be odd.

```
if len(mylist)&1:
    print("list was odd")
elif CheckSomthingElse():
    print("list was even AND CheckSomthingElse was True")
else:
    print("list was even AND CheckSomthingElse was False")
```

Wow in python by the test below % 2 is faster. python must be optimized for it. in some other languages & 1 is faster. this is why it's important to always test.

```
import timeit

MyListOdd=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
MyListEven=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
print("MyListOdd  == ",MyListOdd)
print("MyListEven == ",MyListEven)
print("len(MyListOdd)  == ",len(MyListOdd))
print("len(MyListEven) == ",len(MyListEven))

def TestIfEvenBitwise(MyList):
    if len(MyList)&1:
        return False #Odd
    else:
        return True #Even

def TestIfEvenModulus(MyList):
    if len(MyList)%2:
        return False #Odd
    else:
        return True #Even

print("TestIfEvenBitwise(MyListOdd)  == ",TestIfEvenBitwise(MyListOdd))
print("TestIfEvenModulus(MyListOdd)  == ",TestIfEvenModulus(MyListOdd))
print("TestIfEvenBitwise(MyListEven) == ",TestIfEvenBitwise(MyListEven))
print("TestIfEvenModulus(MyListEven) == ",TestIfEvenModulus(MyListEven))

mysetup = """
MyListOdd=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
MyListEven=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

def TestIfEvenBitwise(MyList):
    if len(MyList)&1:
        return False #Odd
    else:
        return True #Even

def TestIfEvenModulus(MyList):
    if len(MyList)%2:
        return False #Odd
    else:
        return True #Even
"""

print("timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt ='TestIfEvenBitwise(MyListOdd)', number=100000) == ",
      timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt ='TestIfEvenBitwise(MyListOdd)', number=100000))
print("timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt ='TestIfEvenModulus(MyListOdd)', number=100000) == ",
      timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt ='TestIfEvenModulus(MyListOdd)', number=100000))
print("timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt ='TestIfEvenBitwise(MyListEven)', number=100000) == ",
      timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt ='TestIfEvenBitwise(MyListEven)', number=100000))
print("timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt ='TestIfEvenModulus(MyListEven)', number=100000) == ",
      timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt ='TestIfEvenModulus(MyListEven)', number=100000))
```

results of test.

```
MyListOdd  ==  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
MyListEven ==  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
len(MyListOdd)  ==  7
len(MyListEven) ==  6
TestIfEvenBitwise(MyListOdd)  ==  False
TestIfEvenModulus(MyListOdd)  ==  False
TestIfEvenBitwise(MyListEven) ==  True
TestIfEvenModulus(MyListEven) ==  True
timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt ='TestIfEvenBitwise(MyListOdd)', number=100000) ==  0.02574796500000004
timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt ='TestIfEvenModulus(MyListOdd)', number=100000) ==  0.022446242000000005
timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt ='TestIfEvenBitwise(MyListEven)', number=100000) ==  0.026081517000000054
timeit.timeit(setup = mysetup,stmt ='TestIfEvenModulus(MyListEven)', number=100000) ==  0.025758655999999935
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the modulus operator - `%` gives the remainder. To get if even, you need to divide by 2, for example:

```
7 % 2 = 1
8 % 2 = 0
```

The most pythonic way to do it is:

```
def is_even(your_list):
    if not len(your_list) % 2:  # 0 in case of even i.e. No remainder
        return True
    else:
        return False
```